# How to use font files emitted by webpack?

Tags: npm, fonts, webpack, font-awesome, webpack-2

**Summary:**

`webpack` issues, in addition to `bundle.js`, font files for `font-awesome`. These files are not properly referenced in `bundle.js`.

**Details:**

I have an `entry.js` file which outputs to a subdirectory (`webpack`) of a subdirectory (`dist`). `dist` is the standalone, CDN distribuable directory. The structure is such for reasons specific to the site generator (which does not matter for this question).

```
(root folder for the site dev)
│   entry.js
│   webpack.config.js
│
└───dist
    │   index.html
    │
    └───webpack
            674f50d287a8c48dc19ba404d20fe713.eot
            912ec66d7572ff821749319396470bde.svg
            af7ae505a9eed503f8b8e6982036873e.woff2
            b06871f281fee6b241d60582ae9369b9.ttf
            bundle.js
            fee66e712a8a08eef5805a46892932ad.woff
```

`index.html` loads `webpack/bundle.js` and attempts to use Font Awesome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        hello world <i class="fa fa-shower"></i>
        <script src="webpack/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The font files are not correctly referenced, `bundle.js` looks for them in the root of the site while they are in `webpack`, where they were output together with `bundle.js`. in other words `bundle.js` is not aware that webpack.config.js instructed it to go to a subdirectory. The output on the console (console output):

```
index.html:1 GET file:///D:/MegaSync/dev/webpack/testoffonts/dist/af7ae505a9eed503f8b8e6982036873e.woff2 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:1 GET file:///D:/MegaSync/dev/webpack/testoffonts/dist/fee66e712a8a08eef5805a46892932ad.woff net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:1 GET file:///D:/MegaSync/dev/webpack/testoffonts/dist/b06871f281fee6b241d60582ae9369b9.ttf net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

**How to raise this awareness for `bundle.js` so that it references its output-generated peers at the same level it is itself (`/webpack/...` in my case)?**

The component files:

---

`entry.js`:

```
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'
```

---

`webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./entry.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist/webpack', // should use the path module
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "file-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

*Note: this problem does not appear for fonts imported in a CSS file, as of now the only case I have it is with Font Awesome used as a module*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*All credit for the solution goes to [Jiggneshh Gohel](https://github.com/jiggneshhgohel) and his [detailed post on webpack GithHub](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/597#issuecomment-297721105)*

Adding [`publicPath`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/) solves the problem:

```
output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist/webpack', // should use the path module
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/webpack/",
    },
```

The path should be the one the bundle and other emitted files are output to, relative to the root of the exposed site (`http://example.com/`).